# Is it possible to change the ttk.progressBar relief in python?

Tags: python, user-interface, ttk

I have a progress-bar using this code:

```
s = ttk.Style()
s.theme_use('alt')
s.configure("blue.Horizontal.TProgressbar", troughcolor='#4d4d4d', background='#2f92ff', relief="flat")

Pb = ttk.Progressbar(root, style="blue.Horizontal.TProgressbar", orient ="horizontal", length=350, mode="determinate")

Pb.pack()
```

It currently looks like this:

[image]

Here's what the different reliefs look like if you're having a hard time seeing this:

[image]

It currently appears to be "sunken". I want it to be "flat".
I've read documentation for ttk but I can't find anything specific to the progress-bar, so I'm wondering if this is even possible.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `troughrelief` option rather than `relief`.

Try the following:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

s = ttk.Style()
s.theme_use('alt')
s.configure('blue.Horizontal.TProgressbar',
        troughcolor  = '#4d4d4d',
        troughrelief = 'flat',
        background   = '#2f92ff')

pb = ttk.Progressbar(root,
        style  = 'blue.Horizontal.TProgressbar',
        orient = 'horizontal',
        length =  350,
        mode   = 'indeterminate')
pb.pack()
pb.start()

root.mainloop()
```